# Возможно ли нанести вред Пк если код выполняется в виртуальной машине?

Tags: linux, безопасность, виртуальная-машина

Нужно поле для экспериментов в программировании под линукс, нужно ли брать 2-й ноут(дешевый(на случай поломки)) или можно обойтись основным msi raider и VMware Workstation(у меня интел и винда 10 без обновы от спектра и Meltdown).
программист я начинающий не хочу навредить компу

Comment: Нет, не навредит. Делай что задумал

Comment: Если не вспоминать про вирусы, а нужно просто «поле для экспериментов» без цели сломать что-нибудь, то виртуальной машины будет вполне достаточно в качестве «защиты от дурака»